# Mapbox annotation layer rotation resets on map zoom or move

Tags: ios, annotations, transform, mapbox

I'm trying to customize the appearance of the layers of my annotations in mapbox.
I want to rotate every annotation layer.

```
- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation
{
    if (annotation.isUserLocationAnnotation)
        return nil;

    RMMarker *marker;
    CGPoint xy = CGPointFromString(annotation.userInfo);
    marker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
    marker.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(atan2f(xy.x, xy.y) * 180 / M_PI,0,0,1);

    marker.canShowCallout = YES;

return marker;
}
```

It works the first time they load on the map. But when I move or zoom the map they reset back to their initial transform identity matrix.

Any ideas how I could solve this ? Or is it a bug of mapbox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look in `RMMapView.m` at the `annotationTransform`. This gets corrected during movements for things like compass tracking mode, so you'll want to modify things with your own custom transform(s) as this isn't a public API part of this SDK.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I did and it works like I need it now.
Btw, what happened to the mapbox discussions? I cannot access it anymore.