# Animating markers annotation on MapBox (iOS)

Tags: ios, animation, annotations, mapbox

I'm trying to animate some markers initialised with a picture as follows `RMMarker *marker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:lImage anchorPoint:lPoint];`

I get a static image on my map with no problem.
Now, I need it to be more visible than other annotations, so I want to make it blink.

Here's what I already tried:

**Creating scale animation on annotation layer**

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0.70];
[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

CABasicAnimation *bounceAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
bounceAnimation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT;
bounceAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.1, 1.1, 1.0)];
bounceAnimation.toValue   = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(0.8, 0.8, 1.0)];
bounceAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
bounceAnimation.autoreverses = YES;

[layer addAnimation:bounceAnimation forKey:@"animateScale"];

[CATransaction commit];
```

This is working well, except that my callout view is also blinking as it shares the same layer (and Mapbox messes with the animation during the tracking mode, resulting in an incorrect orientation as it is reseted with every move of the user anyway).

**Creating blink animation on annotation layer**

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0.60];
[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

CABasicAnimation *opacityAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
opacityAnimation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT;
opacityAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
opacityAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.3];
opacityAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
opacityAnimation.autoreverses = YES;

[layer addAnimation:opacityAnimation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];

[CATransaction commit];
```

This is less noticeable, but the annotation orientation is correct this time. I still have my callout view blinking on the layer though.

**What I want to do**

I would need a way to animate the marker image without affecting the layer.

The best animation I'd use would be the first one I tried, without the rotation problem.

So far I couldn't animate the UIImage as it doesn't have the `addAnimation: forKey:` call.

I've never played much with animations, so any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with `CABasicAnimation`, as this is what is used for the animated user location annotations in the SDK. You can see this around here:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/blob/509fa7df46ebd654d130ab2f530a8e380bf2bd59/MapView/Map/RMMapView.m#L3593

Could you elaborate on this?

> This is working well, except that my callout view is also blinking as it shares the same layer (and Mapbox messes with the animation during the tracking mode, resulting in an incorrect orientation as it is reseted with every move of the user anyway).

You do bring up a good point that the callout is a sublayer, so it would also blink. This use case hasn't been considered — is it possible for you to deselect your annotation and thus hide the callout?

But what is meant by the latter part?

Comment: Yes, I was inspired by the way you animate the user annotation to try animating my own custom annotations. Unfortunately, I need the annotation to have a callout (I animate it to show the user there's informations here he may want to know more about). For the latter part, it's related with the question you answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754379/mapbox-annotation-layer-rotation-resets-on-map-zoom-or-move) (but it's not clear to me what should be modified)